# I'm looking for a simple GPS tracker that calls a web app when the devise goes in a certain area

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, ios7, gps

I'm trying to achieve very basic employee clock in functionality into my webapp. I'd like it so users can have something on their phone which calls my REST api once when it reaches a designated area and once when it leaves it.

Is there a mobile app that already exists where I can achieve such a thing (connecting it to be web app)? I'm a RoR developer and would ideally not want to build the mobile part myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of an out of the box solution. But windows phone now has geofencing, so what you are looking for is doable.
More details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-geolocation-and-geofencing.aspx) and [here](http://blog.rajenki.com/2014/04/trigger-background-task-using-geofence-windows-phone-8-1/).